# Is $L=\{o^{i}1^{i}o^{j}1^{i} | i,j>0\}$ a context free language?

Tags: automata, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I need to find and to prove (by the pumping lemma or by building a grammar) if $L=\{o^{i}1^{i}o^{j}1^{i} | i,j>0\}$ is a context free language.

I would like to get some help.
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: You can use the pumping lemma to show that $L$ is not context-free. Suppose that it is, and let $p$ be the pumping length. Let $s=0^p1^p01^p$; clearly $s\in L$, so $s$ can be decomposed as $s=uvwxy$ in such a way that $|vwx|\le p$, $|vx|\ge 1$, and $uv^kwx^ky\in L$ for each $k\ge 0$.

- Show that the substring $vwx$ of $s$ must be a substring of one of the substrings $0^p1^p$ and $1^p01^p$.
- Show that in each of the possible locations for $vwx$, $uv^kwx^ky$ is *not* in $L$ if $k=0$. Conclude that $L$ cannot be context-free after all.

Comment: can you tell me please, why people voted down on my explanation?

Comment: @Mithlesh: You’ve shown that two stacks are sufficient, but you’ve not given a rigorous proof that a single stack is insufficient: you’ve only shown that the most obvious approach doesn’t work. What you’ve written *is* a reasonable intuitive justification for *suspecting* that the second language is not context-free, but it’s not a proof. (I did not downvote, by the way.)