# Is $L=\{o^{i}1^{j}o^{j}1^{k}o^{k}1^{i} | i,j,k>0\}$ a context free language?

Tags: automata, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I need some help in finding and proving (by the pumping lemma or by building a grammar) if $L=\{o^{i}1^{j}o^{j}1^{k}o^{k}1^{i} | i,j,k>0\}$ is a context free language.

thanks!

Comment: is $\{a^n c \, b^n | n > 0\}$ a context free language ?

Comment: yes, I think so... I tried to build a grammar for $L=\{o^{i}1^{j}o^{j}1^{k}o^{k}1^{i} | i,j,k>0\}$ .  
s->0S1|0AA0  ,
A->1A0|10

is it ok?

Comment: once you prove that $\{a^n c b^n|n > 0\}$ is context free you know that replacing $c$ by a context free language will still yield a context free languague

Comment: Read a standard book of automaton, you have similar doubt : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613163/is-l-oi1ioj1i-i-j0-a-context-free-language

Answer (score 2):

> $\mathcal L=\{0^{i}1^{j}0^{j}1^{k}0^{k}1^{i} | i,j,k>0\}$ is a context free language?

Yes, here is a grammar that will generate the language:

$$S\to 0A1\\
A\to 0A1|B\\
B\to CC\\
C\to1D0\\
D\to1D0|\varepsilon$$